# How to hide DateTime milliseconds in Datatable column

Tags: c#, asp.net, formatting

I have this code storing date time values in data columns:

```
DataTable apptTable = new DataTable();
apptTable.Columns.Add("Appointment", typeof(DateTime));
apptTable.Columns.Add("Time Scheduled", typeof(DateTime));
```

This displays the full datetime with milliseconds.
[image]

How can I hide the milliseconds?
I've tried passing the datetime as a formatted string like so:
`scheduled.ToString("g");`
but this only works when the data column is of type string. The only problem with having the column be of type string is that it doesn't sort properly.

I am not trying to format the datetime object itself. I am trying to change how the DateTime is displayed in the DataColumn/Gridview. Even if I format the datetime object to remove milliseconds, it still displays in the table as 00.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: I am not trying to format the datetime object itself. I am trying to change how the DateTime is displayed in the DataColumn/Gridview. Even if I format the datetime object to remove milliseconds, it still displays in the table as 00.

Comment: DateTime does not have a format. You need to specify it when you need that object.

Comment: I am trying to change how it is displayed in the data table.

Comment: In any case, this is not a duplicate of the mentioned question.

Comment: it is a duplicate. The DataTable hold the DateTime object. Only when you display it (like in a GridView) you have to specify formatting.

Comment: You'll probably end up with something like this: `<asp:BoundField DataField="Time Scheduled" HeaderText="Date" DataFormatString="{0:g}" />`. That's how you tell the GridView how to format a DateTime when displaying it.

Comment: Thanks mason, that would've worked if I wasn't adding the datatable to the gridview programmatically/in the code behind not in the asp.

Comment: @Bedir How you bind the DataTable isn't really that important. Wherever your columns are declared - whether in the declarative ASPX markup or in the code code behind - you need to make sure you set the correct DataFormatString.

Comment: I ended up using jQuery to remove extra milliseconds: ````$("td").each(function (index) {                
                if ($(this).text().includes(":00 ")) {
                    var currentText = $(this).text();
                    var replacedText = currentText.replace(":00 ", " ");
                    $(this).text(replacedText);
                }
            });````